# Failed to construct CustomElement

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I get an issue using custom elements.

**Error :** `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have children`

```js
'use strict';

class TestCard extends HTMLDivElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.headerNode = document.createElement('div');
    this.bodyNode = document.createElement('div');
    this.headerNode.className = 'card__header';
    this.bodyNode.className = 'card__body';
    this.appendChild(this.headerNode);
    this.appendChild(this.bodyNode);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.classList.add('card');
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['data-header', 'data-body'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      this[attrName.replace('data-', '')] = newValue;
    }
  }

  set header(value) {
    this.headerNode.textContent = value;
    this.setAttribute('data-header', value);
  }

  set body(value) {
    this.bodyNode.innerHTML = value;
    this.setAttribute('data-body', value);
  }
}

customElements.define('test-card', TestCard, {
  extends: 'div'
});
```

```html
<div is="test-card" data-header="Title" data-body="Content"></div>
```

**Creating the WebComponent :**

```
var cardNode = document.createElement('div');
cardNode.setAttribute('is', 'test-card');
cardNode.header = header;
cardNode.body = body;
```

Comment: `this.getElementsByClassName('card__header')[0]` - at that point, your component doesn't have descendant nodes, so that should thrown an error. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve, and more specifically, why you are doing that in the constructor. The only place where you are free to append child nodes is in the component's shadow DOM - but yours doesn't have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things are not allowed in a custom element's constructor. For more info on this check [an older answer by me to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59970158/3744304)).

Amongst others, those are:

- accessing attributes (especially writing attributes, this includes `class` which is considered under control of the person consuming your component)
- accessing children (neither read nor write)

  - **unless you do that in the component's shadow tree**.

To achieve what you want to do, use shadow DOM:

```js
class TestComp extends HTMLElement {
  headerNode = document.createElement('div');
  bodyNode = document.createElement('div');
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.headerNode.className = 'card__header';
    this.bodyNode.className = 'card__body';
    this.bodyNode.part = 'body';
    this.shadowRoot.append(this.headerNode, this.bodyNode);
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.classList.add('card');
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['data-header', 'data-body'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      this[attrName.replace('data-', '')] = newValue;
    }
  }

  set header(value) {
    this.headerNode.textContent = value;
    this.dataset.header = value;
  }

  set body(value) {
    this.bodyNode.innerHTML = value;
    this.dataset.body = value;
  }
}

customElements.define('test-comp', TestComp);

let newTestComp = new TestComp();
newTestComp.header = 'FOOO';
newTestComp.body = '<ul><li><i>BA</i><b>AA</b>R</ul>';
document.body.append(newTestComp);
```

```css
test-comp::part(body) { color: green; }
```

```html
<test-comp data-header="Titre de ma carte" data-body="<h1>Test</h1>"></test-comp>
```

Be aware that using shadow DOM means outside styles won't affect the styling of elements in the shadow tree. To apply styles to those, create a  `<style>` element in the constructor, set it's `textContent` property to your styles, and append that next to your other elements in the shadow DOM.

Instead of using a `style` element, you can also use [Constructable Stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet). You'll probably need a [polyfill](https://github.com/calebdwilliams/construct-style-sheets) because so far [Chromium-based browsers are the only ones supporting it, but support is coming in other browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_cssstylesheet_cssstylesheet) (Firefox has had it for a while behind a flag: Open new tab, navigate to `about:config` and then set `layout.css.constructable-stylesheets.enabled` to `true`).

To allow styling the component's inside from outside CSS, you can specify which elements are allowed to by styled from the outside using the `part="name"` attribute in your shadow DOM and then style it using the [`::part(name)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part) selector in CSS. Added that into the code example.

Comment: Ok thank you it works, but is there any solution without adding a style element in the constructor to use my css class ?

Comment: I've updated my post. You can see my my edit how I'm using the web component in my application.

Comment: Adding the `is` attribute after creating the `div` won't have any effect. Use `const cardNode = document.createElement('div', { is: 'test-card' });` Also I cannot recommend extending `HTMLDivElement` as it a) won't work in Safari without a polyfill, and b) `HTMLDivElement` has no useful API that would make it worth extending anyway.

Comment: If the idea behind extending a div was to get a block level behaviour, instead add this CSS in your page: `test-card { display: block; }`. Please explain why you want to extend `HTMLDivElement`.

Comment: Thank you it works with the option in the `createElement` function.

Comment: The last question, if I don't want to create the web component using JS but by adding the tag in my HTML document, is there any solution ? Like => `<div is="test-card" data-header="Title" data-body="Content"></div>` (with this code, it's not working).

Comment: That code should work, but as mentioned, not in Safari. And again, don't extend div, use a custom tag instead. To check if your component is registered properly, select its tag in the element inspector, then switch to console with the element selected. There, enter `$0.constructor.name`. That should give you `TestCard`.

Comment: No, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor: localName does not match the HTML element interface at new testCard`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243575/discussion-between-connexo-and-tonymx227).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say about the error that you mentioned but there is one more thing which you should change.

Reorder these things in your code from

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.classList.add('card');
    this.headerNode = this.getElementsByClassName('card__header')[0];
    this.bodyNode = this.getElementsByClassName('card__body')[0];
    this.innerHTML = `<div class="card__header"></div>
                      <div class="card__body"></div>`;
  }
```

to

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.classList.add('card');
    this.innerHTML = `<div class="card__header"></div>
                      <div class="card__body"></div>`;
    this.headerNode = this.getElementsByClassName('card__header')[0];
    this.bodyNode = this.getElementsByClassName('card__body')[0];

  }
```

Since you are adding the element with classes `card__header` and `card__body` later in the code, And you are trying to access it that is why `this.headerNode` is `undefined`.

Comment: Still violating *the result must not have children*.

Comment: I ran your code on Stackblitz and it is working fine there. You could try this as well to create the component and setting attribute                                                            ```const newTextComp = document.createElement('test-comp');
  newTextComp.setAttribute('data-header', 'Food');
  newTextComp.setAttribute('data-body', '<ul><li><i>BA</i><b>AA</b>R</ul>');
  document.body.appendChild(newTextComp);                                                                
```

Answer (score -1):

As I commented in Connexo his older answer.
You have to understand the Web Components **lifecycle**: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

When you run `new TestComp()` or `document.createElement("test-comp")`
there is NO DOM Element, only the `constructor` runs, and tells you,
you can't **add** DOM (children) to it (nothing). Only in the `connectedCallback` can you work with **existing** DOM, anything **inside** or **after** your `<test-comp>` **might** not exist yet; see: [wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)

And please optimize that constructor,
any blog or answer showing `this.shadowRoot` inside the `constructor` should be burned

```
  constructor() {
    super() // sets AND returns "this" scope
     .attachShadow({mode:'open'}) // sets AND returns shadowRoot
     .append(
        this.headerNode = document.createElement('div'),
        this.bodyNode = document.createElement('div')
     );
    this.headerNode.className = 'card__header';
    this.bodyNode.className = 'card__body';
  }
```